# Distance between picker multi wheels

Tags: swift, swiftui

There is no way to change the distance between the picker wheels.
The distance between the wheels is not affected by the number of wheels or the width of the frame. How can this be done?

[image]

Here is an example of the code I was referring to. Everything is the same, the only thing I added were extra wheels.

```
extension UIPickerView {
  open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric , height: 150)
  }
}

struct MultiWheelPicker<Data>: View where Data : Hashable {
  let labels: [String]
  let data: [[Data]]
  @Binding var selection: [Data]

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      HStack {
        ForEach(0..<data.count) { column in
          picker(label: labels[column],
                 columnData: data[column],
                 column: column,
                 geometry: geometry)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @ViewBuilder private func picker(
    label: String,
    columnData: [Data],
    column: Int,
    geometry: GeometryProxy
  ) -> some View {
    Picker(label, selection: $selection[column]) {
      ForEach(0..<columnData.count) { row in
        Text(String(describing: columnData[row]))
          .tag(columnData[row])
      }
    }
    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.data.count),
           height: geometry.size.height)
    .clipped()
    Spacer()
  }
}

struct MultiWheelPickerTest: View {
  @State var selection = ["1", "1", "1991"]

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
      Text(verbatim: "Selection: \(selection)")
      MultiWheelPicker(labels: ["Day", "Month", "Year"],
                       data:  [
                        Array(1...31).map { "\($0)" },
                        Array(1...12).map { "\($0)" },
                        Array(1991...2023).map { "\($0)" }
                       ],
                       selection: $selection)
      .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
  }
}
```

These are the settings I use for the picker:

```
.labelsHidden()
    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.data.count),
           height: geometry.size.height)
    .clipped()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, is the picture your desired outcome? Maybe you can add a [example] to your question.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: I have added the reference code

Comment: If spacing is not defined, HStack uses default spaces. Use `HStack(spacing: 0)` to remove default spaces.

Comment: @Asad The indentation is contained by the Picker element itself. Unfortunately HStack has no effect. If you place another element (for example, Text) instead of Picker, then everything will stick together as it should.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961550/swiftui-placing-two-pickers-side-by-side-in-hstack-does-not-resize-pickers